# Calling the method 'SubmitJob' from new-webserviceproxy cmdlet in Powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-5.0

I want to call the method SubmitJob from the cmdlet 'new-webserviceproxy'. The methods exposed from the cmdlet is as follows.

[image]

The definition of the method SubmitJob is as follows

[image]

The method expects many parameters. But we want to pass only two paramters namely 'pJobDefinition' and 'pAction'.

When we pass these two parameters alone we are getting below error.

[image]

Help me to call the method by passing these two parameters alone.

Thanks in advance

Comment: ... what makes you think that can work?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler  i am not sure which is mandatory parameter in the method. I am new to service proxy cmdlets in powershell.

Comment: Is the `$url` you are using a public resource you can share with us? I tried `New-WebServiceProxy 'http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL'` but I didn't get the same methods in my list. Also which PS version are you using? You have 3 listed so it makes it more effort to test this

Comment: What happens if you pass $nulls for the other parameters?

Comment: I am using powershell version 4.0

Comment: Hi After supplying all parameters i am getting the below error. 
Exception calling "SubmitJob" with "23" argument(s): "The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized." 

Through UI i am able to submit with the same parameters, but when i try through powershell i am getting the above error.

Comment: @Venkatakrishnan Again, is the `$url` you are using a public resource you can share with us?

Comment: It's an Intranet url. It won't be accessible publicly.as u suggested I have passed all variables and am getting the above stated error

Answer (score 1):

The creator of the method you are calling defines what parameters are mandatory and which have default values that would allow them to be optional. As the consumer of the method you have no choice but to provide values for all required parameters. You may be able to pass a $null value or use [System.Management.Automation.Language.NullString]::Value to pass a null value to a specific parameter but the ability to do so is not dependent on you, it is solely up to the creator of the method.

What you may be able to do is to create a wrapper function that takes only the two inputs you wish to present and then adds all of the additional parameters with default values that you define. For example:

```
function SomeFunction ($foo,$bar,$foobar){
  #do something
  $foo
  $bar
  $foobar
}

function MyShortFunction ($foo){
  SomeFunction($foo, "a parameter that doesn't change", "some other hardcoded parameter")
}
```

In order to do this however you will need to figure out which "default" parameter values to pass to ensure that the calls work correctly. In short, the creator of the method decides what values are required and you have to ensure you pass those parameters in some way.

Comment: Hi
After supplying all parameters i am getting the below error.

Exception calling "SubmitJob" with "23" argument(s): "The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized."

Through UI i am able to submit with the same parameters, but when i try    
through powershell i am getting the above error.

Comment: Does the webservice or the method require credentials to be explicitly set? That sounds like an authentication issue which is unrelated. If you are having issues authenticating I would post a new question with concise code illustrating the exact issue.

Comment: I have tried by supplying credentials. Still i am getting that error.